# PHP gives different dates for what appears to be the same input

Tags: php, date

PHP Program Extract:

```
$currentDate = date("Y-m-d H:i");
echo $currentDate."<br/>";
echo "It is now " . date('l dS \o\f F Y h:i:s A', $currentDate)."<br />";
echo "It is now " .$currentDate."<br /><br />";
```

Screen Output Extract

```
2013-02-08 01:15
It is now Thursday 01st of January 1970 10:33:33 AM
It is now 2013-02-08 01:15
```

Comment: `date` expects a timestamp, not a formatted string

Comment: @MrCode I think he knows that, in the first case he uses the 24h format (01:15), but with AM/PM the hour must be in 12h Format...

Comment: @Simon, you're right, I missed that :)

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter of [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) should be a timestamp, not a formatted string.

Answer (score 1):

`Date` requires a unix timestamp (integer) as the 2nd argument.  You fed it a string.

Answer (score 0):

`date` expects a timestamp, not a formatted string. Use

```
$currentDate = time(); // returns a timestamp
```

Reference: http://php.net/date

Comment: Yes, and in OP's example would be redundant, as `date()` already acts on the current `time()` timestamp when the second argument to `date()` is omitted.

Answer (score 0):

`date()` assumes that the second parameter is a unix timestamp. 1.1.1970 is the timestamp 0. It tries to interpret your string as a number.

See the [date manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).